# Merging multiple extent html reports using ExtentXReporter

Tags: java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have multiple projects using extent reports to generate html reports and now the problem im running into is integrating these reports.

More or less im looking for a report similar to this
http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentMerge.html

I have report1.html, report2.html ... to be merged to a single html file

Creating single instance of extentrepot won't be solving this issue as these are completely different projects running as part of regression

Can anyone please direct me to an example/poc to integrate this using Extentxreporter

I have mongodb and nodejs installed

Answer (score 1):

The merge utility is no longer available or supported. The recommended solution is to use the Klov server.

Link: https://github.com/extent-framework/klov-server